# How can i get the permanent IP

Tags: php, ip

I want to get the Client Ip with PHP.I allready known that i can get the Ip with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];. But when i post this value in an Database or remember this IP, next day the client adresse is something else and not the same which yesterday.

I allready tried to work with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; but the Ip change every day

Comment: What do you mean by "the permanent IP"? IP addresses are not unique identifiers for users.

Comment: You have to [pay extra money](https://www.godaddy.com/hosting/dedicated-ip) for a static IP address. Obviously, most internet users don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IPs change. That’s the nature of most residential internet connections. Only a comparatively small number of connections have static IPs. IP addresses are an implementation detail of a data routing mechanism, they’re not permanent or unique identifiers.

Comment: Yes but how did google this made.When you login into a google account from another ip adresse the owner of this account get an messages that another user is login into his account.And i want to make this happend with an if statement.So when you create an account on my page the current ip adresse will safe in an database and if you login, the client ip will be check with if ($register_ip == $client_ip) for example.But when everyday there is change of the ip i cant do this

Comment: Google don't do that. They alert when you log in from a new *device*.

Comment: I don’t think Google looks exclusively at the IP. They look at a combination of *geolocation* and *device*.

Comment: Okay can i do this in my code as well.So can i get the device name by an php script?

Comment: No. They set a cookie to identify “known” devices.

Answer (score 0):

The person controlling the HTTP client would need to run it through an Internet connection with a static IP address. To get one they would need to either use an Internet Service Provider that provides static IP addresses by default or one which provides them as an optional extra (and then take that option).

Then they would have to ensure they didn't use a different Internet connection to make a request in the future (e.g. by using their laptop in a coffee shop instead of at home, or connecting from their phone while connected via cellular broadband).

---

They could also use a proxy server that was connected using a static ip. The requests would be relayed via the proxy and that its IP address would be used to connect to the server running the PHP.